# Check which scope value changed when using $watchCollection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have in my controller many filters. If one of them changes I want invoke a function.

```
$scope.$watchCollection("[order, currentFilter, currentPage]", function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {
  if(newValue === oldValue) return;
  $scope.queryModel();
});
```

However I want to make the callback a little more complex by adding filter specific logic in it like so:

```
$scope.$watchCollection("[order, currentFilter, currentPage]", function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {
  if(newValue === oldValue) return;
  $scope.queryModel();
  if(/* order changed */) { /* do stuff */ }
});
```

So my question is this: **What is the most elegant way to find out from inside the callback function which filter changed?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: wouldn't be easier to watch each filter separately instead of watching all filters together (in one array) and then try to distinguish which one changed?

Comment: I thought about this option as well. If there isn't any obvious/elegant solution, this is what I will do eventually. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to write multiple if statements you can do something like this:

```
$scope.$watchCollection("[order, currentFilter, currentPage]", function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {
  if(newValue === oldValue) return;

  var functionMap = {
     order : function () { // do staff for the order filter },
     currentFilter: function () { },
     currentPage : function () { }
  };

  if (newValue)
  {
     functionMap[newValue.filterName]();
  }
});
```